# How To Display Image Into Devexpress GridView / Devexpress Card View From Mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, devexpress

Here I would like to ask, how to display the image data into DevExpress DevExpress gridview or CardView.
For I will take a picture of data from mysql database that I keep with BLOB data type.

how or its code if using visual basic.?

for Code that I use:

```
Dim Query As String = "SELECT FTO.ALM_NIM as FOTO_ID, FTO.ALM_FOTO as FOTO FROM tbl_foto_alumni as FTO"

Using DA As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter(Query, MyKonection)
   Dim DTwisda As New DataTable
   DA.Fill(DTwisda)
   if Dtwisda.Rows.Count > 0 Then
      GridControl.Datasource = DTwisda
      MainView = CardView1
      Dim RepItemImg As New Repository.RepositoryItemPictureEdit()
      RepItemImg.SizeMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.PictureSizeMode.Stretch
      RepItemImg.BestFitWidth = 100
      RepItemImg.CustomHeight = 150
      With CardView1.Columns("FOTO")
           .ColumnEdit = RepItemImg
      End With
      With CardView1
           .OptionsBehavior.FieldAutoHeight = True
           .MaximumCardRows = 2
           .MaximumCardColumns = 6
      End With
   End If
End Using
```

To Screnshoot my program and the results of calling the data from the database, Please Check The Attachment.
already I attach the following word file.

[ScreenShoot_Program](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz16MQvhsMGxdmxqZV8wdm5Qb2c/view?usp=sharing)

Please Help and Give The Solution.

Regards,

Tafary

Comment: Did you try setting the RepositoryItemPictureEdit's PictureStoreMode property to ByteArray?

Comment: not yet, 
How to possible to do with my data and will display to Gridview / Card View using RepositoryItemPictureEdit.?

Can You give me a solution.?

Thank's before..

Comment: You can set the property in the grid control's designer or at runtime:

RepItemImg.PictureStoreMode = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.PictureStoreMode.ByteArray;

Comment: ok.  It's Done Brendon.,
Thank's...

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code:

```
Dim row As DataRow
            Dim i As Integer
            For Each row In myDt.Rows
                Column = New DataColumn
                With Column
                    .DataType = GetType(Bitmap)
                    ' .DefaultValue = Base64ToImage(row("Photo"))
                    .Unique = False
                    .ColumnName = "EmpPhoto"
                End With
                If Not myDt.Columns.Contains("EmpPhoto") Then
                    myDt.Columns.Add(Column)
                End If
                myDt.Rows(i)("EmpPhoto") = Base64ToImage(row("Photo"))
                i += 1
                myDt.AcceptChanges()
            Next
            i = 0
            'myDt.Rows.Add(Column.DefaultValue)

 Public Function Base64ToImage(base64String As String) As Image
    Try
        ' Convert Base64 String to byte[]
        Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)
        ' Convert byte[] to Image
        ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length)
        Dim image1 As Image = Image.FromStream(ms, True)
        Return image1
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```